# Add custom <li>-element to wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus

How can I add a custom < li>-element to wp_nav_menu()? My menu includes already all my categories, but it should also include a < li>-element that contains a search form.

From header.php

```
    <nav>
      <?php
      $args = array(
        'theme_location' => 'nav_main'
        );

      wp_nav_menu($args);
     ?>
     <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </nav>
```

--Edit--

This is how it looks now:

[image]

This is how it should look:

[image]

Comment: can you please share the code?

Comment: What code exactly?

Comment: Are you wanting to add it at the beginning or end? If so you can use the `items_wrap` parameter to just inject it.

Comment: it will be best if you include WordPress nav menu code and output code as well.

Comment: I added two screenshots.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Could you please give me the code for this?

Comment: So, you want your code to be included inside <li> inside <ul></ul>

Comment: @Milan Uptech Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`wp_nav_menu()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) has an `items_wrap` parameter which contains this by default:

```
<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>
```

So you can pass it the above default plus any appended string:

```
$search_form = get_search_form( false ); // Return not echo

$items_wrap = '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s';
$items_wrap .= sprintf( '<li id="searchItem">%1$s</li></ul>', $search_form );

wp_nav_menu( array(
    'items_wrap' => $items_wrap,
) );
```